# U-SQL Tables vs SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

So here's where I'm at.

I'm storing huge amounts of data in Data Lake Store. But when I want to make a report (it can be a month's worth), I want to schematize it into a table to refer to over and over again when querying upon it.

Should I just use the built in database feature that Data Lake Analytics provides by creating U-SQL tables (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621301.aspx) or should I create this table in SQL Data Warehouse? I guess what I really want to know is what are the pros and cons of either case and when is it best to use either?

By the way, I'm a noob in this Microsoft Azure world. Still actively learning.

Comment: How did you get on with this?  It would be good to get some feedback on your approach and what pros and cons you found.

Answer (score 1):

At this point it depends on what you want to do with the data.

If you need interactive report queries, then moving the data into a SQL DB or DW schema is recommended at this point until ADLA provides interactive query capabilities.

If you need the tables during your data preparation steps, want to use partitioning to manage data life cycles, need to run U-SQL queries that can benefit from the clustering and data distribution offered by U-SQL tables, you should use U-SQL tables.

Comment: What exactly is "interactive report queries"? I keep hearing about this. If I were to import that resulted tables into Power BI and perform analysis from there, isn't that essentially interactive queries?

Comment: Today you can access and load CSV files in Azure Data Lake from PowerBI. But you copy the data and then do your reporting in PowerBI.

An interactive report query is a query against the data (normally in a table) that gets often generated by the reporting tool and then sent to the query processor of the data store for processing. Normally these queries are expected to be executed fast, synchronously and return their results directly (via JDBC, ODBC, ADO.Net).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. From what I read, it seems like choosing "Open in Power BI" under the SQL Data Warehouse portal is an instance of such

Comment: Indeed. That is an instance of such. If you feel satisfied with the answers, please mark the answer :).